# Default representation of checkbox/radio lists

Tags: checkbox, radio-button, checkboxlist, radiobuttonlist, yii2

I would like active field to render checkbox/radio lists in a specific way (as Bootstrap's button groups)
Currently I create those fields like this

```
        echo $form->field($model,'foo')->inline()->checkboxList
        (
            $fooList,
            [
                'class' => 'btn-group',
                'data-toggle' => 'buttons',
                'item' => function ( $index , $label , $name , $checked , $value )
                {
                    return Html::checkbox
                    (
                        $name,
                        $checked,
                        [
                            'value' => $value,
                            'label' => $label,
                            'container' => false,
                            'labelOptions' =>
                            [
                                'class' => $checked ? 'btn btn-primary active' : 'btn btn-primary',
                            ],
                        ]
                    );
                }
            ]
        );
```

What is the *right* way to achieve this behavior application-wide?

I probably should extend `yii\helpers\Html` and override it's methods creating those lists. But how do I make active field use my Html instead of the default?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways to solve the problem is to create a custom input widget.